# Exercise 1.1.6 in Additive Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, additive-combinatorics

I'm having trouble understanding Exercise 1.1.6 in *Additive Combinatorics* by Tao and Vu.

> 1.1.6 Consider a set $A$ as above. Show that there exists a subset $\{v_1, \ldots, v_d\}$ of $Z$ with $d = O(\log \frac{|Z|}{|A|})$ such
>   that
>
> $|A + [0,1]^d \cdot (v_1, \ldots, v_d)| \geq |Z|/2$.

"As above" just means that $A \subseteq Z$, where $Z$ is a finite group. Here was my first attempt:

> Let $A_1, \ldots, A_d$ be defined by the recurrence relation $A_{i+1}
> = A_i \cup (A_i + v_{i+1})$, with $A_0 = A$. Then, $A_d = A + [0,1]^d \cdot (v_1, \ldots, v_d)$. By Exercise 1.1.5, we have
>
> $|A_{i+1}| = |A_i \cup (A_i + v_{i+1})| \geq |Z| \left[ 1 - \left( 1 -
> \dfrac{|A_i|}{|Z|} \right)^2 \right] = |A_i| \left( 2 -
> \dfrac{|A_i|}{|Z|} \right) \geq |A_i| \left( 2 - \dfrac{|A|}{|Z|}
> \right)$
>
> Thus,
>
> $|A_d| \geq |A| \left( 2 - \dfrac{|A|}{|Z|} \right)^d$
>
> Since $\lim_{|Z| \to \infty} \log(2 - |A|/|Z|) = \log 2$, we can take
>
> $d \geq \log \dfrac{|Z|}{|A|} \dfrac{1}{\log \left( 2 -
> \frac{|A|}{|Z|} \right)} - \dfrac{\log 2}{\log \left( 2 -
> \frac{|A|}{|Z|} \right)} = O \left( \log \dfrac{|Z|}{|A|} \right)$

However, applying this method to Exercise 1.1.7 gives a tighter bound than the question requests.

> 1.1.7 Consider a set $A$ as above. Show that there exists a subset $\{v_1, \ldots, v_d\}$ of $Z$ with $d := O(\log \frac{|Z|}{|A|} + \log \log(10 + |Z|))$ such
>   that
>
> $A + [0,1]^d \cdot (v_1, \ldots, v_d) = Z$.

Since $Z$ is finite, the removal of cardinality shouldn't matter, and, if the solution to Exercise 1.1.6 were valid, then we could simply take

$d \geq \log \dfrac{|Z|}{|A|} \dfrac{1}{\log \left( 2 - \frac{|A|}{|Z|} \right)} = O \left( \log \dfrac{|Z|}{|A|} \right)$

which doesn't have the $\log \log (10 + |Z|)$ term, suggesting I am in error.

Since this is self-study, I have no instructor to whom to turn.

- Am I understanding the big O notation correctly? (In particular that $A$ is fixed, that $n = |Z|$,  and that $\log(2 - |A|/|Z|)$ is essentially a constant)
- Is my solution to 1.1.6 correct? If not, why does it fail?
- Whence comes the $\log \log (10 + |Z|)$ term?

And, more generally,

- Are there written solutions to the exercises for this textbook available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the (silly) error:

$|A_i| \left( 2 - \dfrac{|A_i|}{|Z|} \right) \leq |A_i| \left( 2 - \dfrac{|A|}{|Z|} \right)$

Comment: The argument can then be fixed by taking $d$ to be the _smallest_, and then bounding $|A_i| (2 - \frac{|A_i|}{|Z|} ) \geq |A_i| (2 - \frac{|A_{d-1}|}{|Z|} )$, so that $|A_d| \geq |A| (3/2)^2$. Importantly, this method breaks down when trying to get $A_d = Z$.

Answer (score 2):

The big $ O $ notation means "something whose norm or absolute value is bounded by a constant times whatever is inside the brackets".
An important example is $ O (1) $ which means uniformly bounded (by an absolute constant such as 3 or 280).

Implicitly, in any case the constant should NEVER depend on what lies inside the brackets, otherwise anything would be a big $ O $ of anything. $ |Z| $ would be a $ O (1) $ since it is bounded by $ 1 $ times the "constant" $|Z|$...

So when you consider
$\log(2 - |A|/|Z|)$ as a constant, that is wrong since it does depend on what lies inside your big $ O $, but you could argue that it lies between $0 $ and log $(2) $ no matter what. However, MOST IMPORTANTLY: the direction of your inequality is wrong. $ f (x) $ is $ O (x) $ means the absolute value of $f (x) $ is LESS than a constant times $ x $.

Another remark, when you have $|Z|$ tend to infinity in an expression involving $ A $, this doesn't really make sense if you don't control the behaviour of $A $ whose very definition depends on $Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, considering $\log(2 - |A|/|Z|)$ as a "constant" is assuming that $|A|$ is fixed and $|Z| \to \infty$, which makes the term bounded by $\log 2$. The inequality, however, is _not_ wrong because it is saying that if $d$ is greater than this number, then the result is true, so we simply take $d$ to be the next greatest integer, which is $O(\log(|Z|/|A|)$. Finally, understanding the meaning of the big O is my primary concern. $A$ could be fixed and $Z_1 \subseteq Z_2 \subseteq \cdots$ could be a chain of groups containing $A$, so $A$ doesn't necessarily depend on $Z$.

Comment: Just pointing these out  as things to be aware of in general. I still think that you need to reverse your inequalities though.

Comment: No, the inequality is correct. When $d$ is greater than this value (call it $x$), then, with probability greater than $0$, there are $v_1, \ldots, v_d \in Z$ such that $|A_d| \geq |Z|/2$. Thus, there is an integer between $x$ and $x+1$ that we may assign to $d$. Thus, $d < x+1 = O(\log |Z|/|A|)$, so $d = O(\log |Z|/|A|)$. This is implied and omitted for brevity, and it is not the issue at hand.

Comment: Now you're writing $ d <\ldots $, *that's* the good direction.

Comment: Yes, I am explaining the gaps that are there to make the solution not irritatingly long. It is implied. It's obvious that you can take the next smallest integer which is also $O(\log |Z|/|A|)$.

Comment: Exp (exp (x)) is larger than x^3, that doesn't make it $ O (x^3) $. $12x^3+1 $ on the other hand,  is *less* than some constant (eg 13) times $ x^3 $, that makes it $ O (x^3) $. (To be precise there should be absolute values everywhere)

Comment: The $d \geq x$ is not to establish that $d = O(\log |Z|/|A|)$ but rather to establish the condition that $|A_d| \geq |Z|/2$. The other inequality $d \leq x + 1 = O(\log |Z|/|A|)$ is implied. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes I get it now. However I don't think that making this explicit would be irritating. The way it is right now is kind of disturbing.